# How do I find where Linux application binary files exist?

Tags: centos, binary

An application usually consists of 3 different file types:

- binary files
- configuration files
- application data

Where does Linux (e.g., CentOS, RHEL) store the binary files for a given application? How can I find it out for an application?

Comment: It's unclear whether you mean "executable binary file" (the actual _command_, which in fact may not be a compiled binary at all) or "binary data file".  What is the issue that you are currently having? Are you, for example, trying to find the executable associated with a particular package?

Comment: Ok sorry, I misunderstood you.  I mean the binaries that make up a program or service.

Comment: The real answer is wherever the person packaging the application (i.e. putting it all into an rpm file) wants. You can see their choices with `rpm -q -l $PACKAGENAME` (or `dpkg -L $PACKAGENAME` on debian and derivatives or something else on other distros). But there are *conventions* for where stuff should go - see @Stewart's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `whereis` for this task.

```
$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.5 /etc/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

Comment: And while `whereis` checks the standard path, you can also use `which` to check the actual path (though it won't find "shadowed" duplicates).

Answer (score 2):

To find the binary itself, another method is `type`.

```
$ type python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
$
```

In terms of location for configuration files and data files, the best place to determine that is often the relevant `man` page.

```
$ man python3 | grep -A10 FILES
FILES AND DIRECTORIES
       These are subject to difference depending on local installation conven‐
       tions;  ${prefix}  and  ${exec_prefix}  are  installation-dependent and
       should be interpreted as for GNU software; they may be the  same.   The
       default for both is /usr/local.

       ${exec_prefix}/bin/python
              Recommended location of the interpreter.

       ${prefix}/lib/python<version>
       ${exec_prefix}/lib/python<version>
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `which` like so:

```
$ which zoom
/usr/bin/zoom
```

which is likely a symbolic link, so to find the actual real path

```
ls -la $(which zoom)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Apr 24 07:19 /usr/bin/zoom -> /opt/zoom/ZoomLauncher
```

Comment: In case that gives another symlink (it doesn't in the case of zoom), you can use `namei` to traverse the chain.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity that's very cool !  I've never used that before, but I will now!

Answer (score 0):

In general, refer to the file-system-heirarchy (FSH) for this:

https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html

A direct (and simplified) answer to your question is:

- binary files:

  - `/usr/bin` for executables
  - `/usr/lib` for shared objects (libraries)
- configuration files

  - `/etc`
- application data

  - `/var` for read-write stuff
  - `/usr/share` for architecture-independent, read-only data (like images)

If you are using a debian-based system, you can find what files are deployed by a specific application (package) with `dpkg -L`:

```
$ dpkg-query -L xclip
/usr/bin/xclip
/usr/share/doc/xclip/README
/usr/share/doc/xclip/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/xclip/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/xclip/copyright
/usr/share/man/man1/xclip.1.gz
```

In this (abbreviated) case, we see package `xclip` has a binary in `/usr/bin`, some changelog and copyright stuff in `/usr/share/doc/xclip` and a man page in `/usr/share/man/man1`.

Other distros have other tools for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

### Shellscript `what-about`

I use the shellscript `what-about` in order to show some basic information of executable programs, that are available via `PATH`,

- where it is located
- what package it belongs to or can be installed from
- what kind of program it is (binary executable code, shellscript, shell built-in, alias, link ...)

This `bash` shellscript uses the tool `dpkg`, that belongs to Debian and Ubuntu and can be used also in Linux distros developed from those two distros. If you want to see the whole content of a [debian] program package, you can use `dpkg` or `emacs` according to [this link to AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412541/how-to-find-out-what-is-installed-in-the-package-deb/1412549#1412549).

If you want to find the program package the program belongs to in some other distro, CentOS and RHEL were mentioned in the original question, you must replace `dpkg` with the corresponding tool.

Here it is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

LANG=C
inversvid="\0033[7m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
 echo "Usage: ${0##*/} <program-name>"
 echo "Will try to find corresponding package"
 echo "and tell what kind of program it is"
 exit 1
fi
command="$1"

str=;for ((i=1;i<=$(tput cols);i++)) do str="-$str";done
tmp="$command"
first=true
curdir="$(pwd)"
tmq=$(which "$command")
tdr="${tmq%/*}"
tex="${tmq##*/}"
if test -d "$tdr"; then cd "$tdr"; fi
#echo "cwd='$(pwd)' ################# d"

while $first || [ "${tmp:0:1}" == "l" ]
do
 first=false
 tmp=${tmp##*\ }
 tmq="$tmp"
 tmp=$(ls -l "$(which "$tmp")" 2>/dev/null)
 tdr="${tmq%/*}"
 tex="${tmq##*/}"
 if test -d "$tdr"; then cd "$tdr"; fi
# echo "cwd='$(pwd)' ################# d"
 if [ "$tmp" == "" ]
 then
  tmp=$(ls -l "$tex" 2>/dev/null)
  tmp=${tmp##*\ }
  if [ "$tmp" == "" ]
  then
   echo "$command is not in PATH"
#   package=$(bash -ic "$command -v 2>&1")
#   echo "package=$package XXXXX 0"
   bash -ic "alias '$command' > /dev/null 2>&1" > /dev/null 2>&1
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]
   then
    echo 'looking for package ...'
    package=$(bash -ic "$command -v 2>&1"| sed -e '0,/with:/d'| grep -v '^$')
   else
    echo 'alias, hence not looking for package'
   fi
#   echo "package=$package XXXXX 1"
   if [ "$package" != "" ]
   then
    echo "$str"
    echo "package: [to get command '$1']"
    echo -e "${inversvid}${package}${resetvid}"
   fi
   else
    echo "$tmp"
   fi
 else
  echo "$tmp"
 fi
done
tmp=${tmp##*\ }
if [ "$tmp" != "" ]
then
 echo "$str"
 program="$tex"
 program="$(pwd)/$tex"
 file "$program"
 if [ "$program" == "/usr/bin/snap" ]
 then
  echo "$str"
  echo "/usr/bin/snap run $command     # run $command "
  sprog=$(find /snap/"$command" -type f -iname "$command" \
   -exec file {} \; 2>/dev/null | sort | tail -n1)
  echo -e "${inversvid}file: $sprog$resetvid"
  echo "/usr/bin/snap list $command    # list $command"
  slist="$(/usr/bin/snap list "$command")"
  echo -e "${inversvid}$slist$resetvid"
 else
  package=$(dpkg -S "$program")
  if [ "$package" == "" ]
  then
   package=$(dpkg -S "$tex" | grep -e " /bin/$tex$" -e " /sbin/$tex$")
   if [ "$package" != "" ]
   then
    ls -l /bin /sbin
   fi
  fi
  if [ "$package" != "" ]
  then
   echo "$str"
   echo " package: /path/program  [for command '$1']"
   echo -e "${inversvid} $package ${resetvid}"
  fi
 fi
fi
echo "$str"
#alias=$(grep "alias $command=" "$HOME/.bashrc")
alias=$(bash -ic "alias '$command' 2>/dev/null"| grep "$command")
if [ "$alias" != "" ]
then
 echo "$alias"
fi
type=$(type "$command" 2>/dev/null)
if [ "$type" != "" ]
then
 echo "type: $type"
elif [ "$alias" == "" ]
then
 echo "type: $command: not found"
fi
cd "$curdir"
```

This shellscript can find a program that is 'behind' a link or a series of links.

See also [this link to AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736432/how-to-get-the-location-of-a-program-in-ubuntu-terminal/1413975#1413975), where there are some demo examples.

Answer (score -1):

> asked 4 years ago
>
> Where does Linux (e.g., CentOS, RHEL) store the binary files for a given application?

"Linux" does not necessarily decide where to store the binary files for a given application; it depends on the application and if it's a Linux system type application then I suppose based on convention as described by the File Hierarchy Standard which may or not be followed.  So you really truly cannot be sure sure.

For example, if you build something from source and do `./configure --prefix=/somewhere/else` you can override the [default] location they would have resided.  And it is not just building from source, commercial software that you pay big bucks for licensing for example, their install gui will give a default location to install to such as `/opt` which by convention is a good place.  And another example is Intel's MKL/MPI install (now known as openAPI) that default is `/opt/intel/oneapi` but it can be located anywhere.  And a linux admin or user you may have legitimately good reason to put something **anywhere**.

So really the only **good** way to find where something is stored is to use the **find** command and search everywhere and then when multiple locations happen to show up (because numerous admins have been involved over however long and there was no digital housekeeping done) you will have to make a determination as to which is correct.

- using `which` to find the location of an **executable?** binary that only resides in the `PATH` environment variable has major hopefully obvious shortcomings; it only responds on the first occurrence and only if it is in PATH.
- using `whereis` which I am not familiar with, does not work which I assume if your binary is installed outside of the rpm method; I have a executable in my PATH that installed via the manufacturer's installer and is not rpm based and `whereis` does not find it however `which` does because I have manually placed it in `PATH`.
- the same seems to happen with `type`.  It works for `type python3` or `type gcc` but it does not work for numerous others just like `whereis` does not.

> I mean the binaries that make up a program or service.

Then **assuming** the service was installed via rpm per normal convention on a RHEL/CentOS/Rocky linux *style* distribution if you know what rpm the binary came from then I would use

```
repoquery --installed -l <rpm_name>
```

If you don't know then it would be a matter or repoquery'ing all installed rpm's and doing a `grep` for that binary name on all that output.  But still, `find` is probably the most reliable method if you're not 100% sure how it was installed, and by whom.  Sorry, I don't know what the `repoquery` equivalent is on a debian style linux distribution.  The `which` and `whereis` and `type` ways, i would first try it's minimal keystrokes and time and if it's found great, but if not found do not believe what you are looking for is truly not *on the system*.